# How to get EF to either not save children or load children after a post (save)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have this method (generated using the scaffolding process):

```
    // POST: api/Recipients
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostRecipient([FromBody] Recipient recipient)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.Recipients.Add(recipient);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction("GetRecipient", new { id = recipient.Id }, recipient);
    }
```

If I try to post a `Recipient` object with the child object `primaryContact` set to some value, EF gives me a "Bad Request" error.

So, currently, I am posting the `Recipient` object from my Angular 2 project, setting `primaryContact` property to null in the Javascript so that EF doesn't try to save that child object. When I do this, however, EF does not give me the child object immediately in the response (it does after a second `get` call).

How can I:

1. Avoid setting the Javascript property to null so that EF doesn't try to save it
2. OR make it so that EF immediately loads the primaryContact in the returned response after posting the `Recipient`.

   ```
   // GET: api/Recipients/5
   [HttpGet("{id}")]
   public async Task<IActionResult> GetRecipient([FromRoute] int id)
   {
       if (!ModelState.IsValid)
       {
           return BadRequest(ModelState);
       }

       var recipient = await _context.Recipients.Include(rec => rec.PrimaryContact).SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == id);

       if (recipient == null)
       {
           return NotFound();
       }

       return Ok(recipient);
   }
   ```

Here is the `Recipient` Entity:

```
[Table("Recipient")]
public class Recipient
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string Zip { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string WorkPhone { get; set; }
    public string HomePhone { get; set; }
    [Column(TypeName = "datetime")]
    public DateTime DateAdded { get; set; }
    public int? PrimaryContactId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PrimaryContactId")]
    public Contact PrimaryContact { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself after understanding exactly what the `CreateAtAction()` method is doing.

`CreateAtAction()` essentially creates a "fake" response, filling the body with the same `recipient` object that `PostRecipient` was given (which is why it came up as null in the post action's response).

All I had to do was add `recipient = await _context.Recipients.Include(rec => rec.PrimaryContact).SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == recipient.Id);` immediately after the context saved changes.

Fix:

```
    // POST: api/Recipients
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> PostRecipient([FromBody] Recipient recipient)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        _context.Recipients.Add(recipient);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        recipient = await _context.Recipients.Include(rec => rec.PrimaryContact).SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == recipient.Id);

        return CreatedAtAction("GetRecipient", new { id = recipient.Id }, recipient);
    }
```